# Align table under text in wikipedia

Tags: css, wikipedia

i am working with wikipedia editor for the first time.
so I dont have so much experience.

Question:
I have numbering in my paragraph and I am trying to align vertically the table and image under the numbering text but it did not work.
You find below my codes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VIPK.png)
How can I get there please?

Thank you.

BG

Adel

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Do you have an image of the bad look?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.